# New to VBS. Expecting end of statement on 60'th character

Tags: vbscript

When I put the END at the 60'th character. It says it needs an 'expected statement'
Here's the code.

```
Set colComputers2 = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ScheduledJob") end T = "C:\AntiVirusNet.vbs"D = "********" & Hou & "" & Min & "00.000000+000"
```

Help???

Comment: Fundamental issue is you haven't grasped VBScript syntax or any version of VB for that matter. `End` is not a valid statement, it say's *"expected statement"* because it understands the term `End` but expects it to be accompanied by something else as a termination of a block of code be it `End If`, `End Select`, `End Sub`, `End Function` they are all valid but not on their own. Suggest you go back and read a good VBScript tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the word end.

```
Set colComputers2 = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ScheduledJob")
T = "C:\AntiVirusNet.vbs"
D = "********" & Hou & "" & Min & "00.000000+000"
```

PS: From Help https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=2764

> Construct  Terminating Statement

```
Sub 
 End Sub 

Function 
 End Function 

If 
 End If 

Class 
 End Class 

With 
 End With 

Select 
 End Select
```

Comment: And add some carriage returns. This isn't a one liner.

Comment: Unless you separate the statements with colons.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Why argue semantics it's not even valid like that anyway and I doubt the OP has even glanced at a VBScript tutorial.